# mdworker couldn't find bundle

Tags: osx-lion, macbook-pro, spotlight

This error is showing up in my syslog every few seconds:

```
Aug 28 06:02:04 Roys-MacBook-Pro mdworker[1257]: (Error) Import: Couldn't find bundle identifier for /Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application Loader.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/MZSpotlight.mdimporter
```

mdworker seems to be connected to Spotlight, and the error mentions Spotlight in it.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.4. What's the cause of the error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd since solved this problem quite some time ago.

If I recall correctly, it is due to some Xcode update with some left over files that aren't deleted from the old version.

Can't recall the exact files, but ya, after deleting those files the errors were gone.

Hope it helps others.